# CISCO: Copy one UDP unicast packet to other destination

Tags: udp

I have following scenario: host A and host B are sending to each other unicast UDP packet.
I need that same message from host A will arrive also to host C - with new DST address.

How to configure my cisco IE3000 switch so that this will happen?

Thank you :)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that on a switch - a switch doesn't copy packets and one of this type can't change L3 destinations (requiring destination NAT).

You could use port mirroring to duplicate egress frames out of a certain port. Then you could run a forwarder on the monitor port that resends the UDP datagrams elsewhere.

Such a forwarding service likely exists already and would be rather trivial to program, but programming and resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

If Host C is connected to the same switch you could alternatively mirror directly to its port and use promiscuous mode (and possibly packet capturing) to receive the UDP datagrams.

Of course, the correct approach to this type of problem would be to use multicast.